# Ordering factor levels using tidyeval

Tags: r, tidyeval

I have a `dataframe` which looks like this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  x = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"),
  score = c(1, 4, 6, 3),
  order = c(1, 4, 3, 2)
)
```

The levels of `my_df$x` look like this:

```
> my_df$x
[1] V1 V2 V3 V4
Levels: V1 V2 V3 V4
```

I want to be able to reorder the levels of `x` based on the `order` column like this:

```
my_df_ <- my_df %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, x[order]))
my_df_$x
[1] V1 V2 V3 V4
Levels: V1 V4 V3 V2
```

But I want to be able to do this within a function using `tidyeval` and cannot for the like of me figure out how...I am happy to be able to pass either strings (`"x"`) or expressions (`x`) to the function.

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution using `forcats` would be something along the lines of:

```
my_fn <- function(df, x, o) {

  o_ <- enquo(o)
  x_ <- enquo(x)
  x_name <- quo_name(x_)

  df %>% 
    mutate(!!x_name := fct_reorder(!!x_, !!o_))
}
my_fn(my_df, x, order)
```